# How can a slipper assist clutch on a motorcycle provide a friction zone?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, mechanisms

Most modern motorbikes come with a slip and assist clutch - this is typically provided by a mechanism of ramps that will force the clutch plates apart when the engine drives the wheel under hard downshifting (the slipper function) and also a set of ramps that will engage the clutch plates tighter together when the engine drives the wheel, allowing the use of lighter springs(the assist function)

Now my question is this:

In regular motorcycle clutches, it is quite simple to hold the lever in a position where the clutch is allowed to slip a little under moderate acceleration and increased revs. This does eat the clutch up, but not so much for very slow speed riding  - for e.g in bumper to bumper traffic crawls or trying to negotiate tricky offroad sections at a very low speed (lower than the bike will with clutch engaged in 1st gear).

When you consider a clutch with assist, there is no "friction zone" because any torque applied by the engine if the wheel resists causes the clutch plates to bind rock solid - If you were to hold the lever halfway, the assist function will fight the force you are applying on the lever - it would feel as if the springs are getting super stiff - and the more you increased throttle, the more the clutch would engage.

In other words it should be impossible to use the friction zone and have the engine and wheel speeds mismatched due to slipping.

This means on offroad sections there is really no way to control the bike by way of the clutch - you either have full traction or you have none.

My understanding is that the whole technique of riding will need to be adapted to this - you would have to always be either low throttle clutch fully disengaged and ride the momentum of the bike, or be fully engaged with throttle opened up.
There would be no way to ride the bike at a speed lower than the 1st gear minimum other than while coasting with brakes applied and clutch disengaged.

Is my analysis correct?
If not, what is the real picture?

Also if you are a dirt bike rider who has done technical trails, trials and so on with both vanilla and slip/assist clutches, can you explain if there is a difference you experience between the two?

Thanks in advance